# CodeIgniter How to add a value to SQL database index value automatically?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How to set value in database automatically without any action after a number of days ? ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set cron on your server.
For cron also you need to take care that your method is accessible without any session. You can use some token verification for it.

Other then this You can create a mysql procedure but that mysql procedure also you need to call through your code.

Comment: Thanks Amit ... Thats the point mate, I don't want to call the function from page code at all .. everything is pointing towards Cron ... Is it easy to understand?

Answer (score 0):

You must setup a controller with a function to do your logic or in a CLI
reference : [CLI Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html)

and execute this function in a ksh file or directly with a cron job to schedule this action

Comment: Script written for the Unix operating system; contains a list of commands that can be run within a Korn Shell or Bourne-Again Shell; can be viewed and edited with a text editor.